# Drupal Views search by one field and sort by another

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a problem with Drupal Views.

I have a content type "Company". "Company" has a "City" field (taxonomy term reference) and "Company type" field (A,B,C).

How can I – inside a view – search for City and order by Company Type at the same time?

For example I want to search for Paris. And then I want all Paris Companies sorted initially by Company Type. First A, then B, then C.

How to enable sorting like that?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Sorry. I use views to make that search. I don't know if is it possible to do with views or if I must develop a custom script to do that. I don't have code now. I'm looking for suggestions to know how do that with drupal

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little bit on how you display your companies. As table or as list? But generally you simply can add multiple sort criterions.

[image]

Comment: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/pm2eamng3mgmk14/search.png?dl=0
This is my view. I need to search all companies in a searched city

Comment: @AlessandroZaccheroni — First add a third filter criteria "City" and check the checkbox to **expose** this one. Exposed filters are accessible to your website users then.